# Asp.net core Database Connectivity not working on Local IIS Hosting

Tags: asp.net-core, database-connection

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Defaultconnection" value="Server=INNO1-395LFP\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ASK_DB;uid=sa;password=Sa@123456;Trusted_Connection=True;" /></appSettings>
</configuration>
```

This is my app.config file and I am not able to connect to database in asp.net core in Local IIS Hosting

Comment: I think you forgot to include your code

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Defaultconnection" value="Server=INNO1-395LFP\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ASK_DB;uid=sa;password=Sa@123456;Trusted_Connection=True;" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>

Comment: when i am my application host in  local iis then my database connection not working remaing when run in develpment face like local host  work fine

Comment: make sure your local sql is running

Comment: Share us the code you read app.config. What is the error? What is your project type? Why did you store connection in app.config?